# Why doesn't Graphics show up?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to save all drawstring which is done with the codes at the bottom half. I am saving it by saving the "Points" in a List type. The purpose of saving is because I want to have the ability to delete a particular drawing. All other drawings will be retained and only the one which wants to be deleted will be removed. My main query is why can't I use the same code with some minor editing(Top half of the code is the code I use to add new drawstring) that I use to draw to redraw when I am deleting a particular drawing.

```
Side_pictureBox.ImageLocation = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"pictures for app\Bus_Nearside.png";
Side_pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\pictures for app\Bus_Nearside.png");
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(Side_pictureBox.Image);
if (Tagged_Remarks_listBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
  for (int x = 0; x <= NumberingPosition.Count - 1; x++)
  {
    if (x != 0)
    {
      using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
      {
        gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        Font drawFont = new Font("Calibri (Body)", 15);
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        //MessageBox.Show(Numbering[u] + NumberingPosition[u]);
        gr.DrawString(Numbering[x], drawFont, drawBrush, NumberingPosition[x]);
      }
    }
    Side_pictureBox.Image = bm;
    Side_pictureBox.Invalidate();
  }
```

//Above code is when I first drawstring ,Below Code is to redraw when deleting particular drawing//

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(Side_pictureBox.Image);


                    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
                    {
                        gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                        String drawString = numbering_for_digram.ToString();
                        Font drawFont = new Font("Calibri (Body)", 15);
                        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);

                        gr.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, lastPoint);
                        Numbering.Add(drawString);


                        drawFont.Dispose();
                        drawBrush.Dispose();
                    }

                    Side_pictureBox.Image = bm;
```

Comment: Because the PictureBox won't repaint itself until **AFTER** the loop is done.  ...the MessageBox stops the loop.  Do you really need to see the changes **while** the loop is running?

Comment: Are you sure you want to dump all that into the Bitmap and not onto the PBox? (Just asking..) - Also: You are leaking your Font and even the Brush.. Use `using` for the formaer and `Brushes.Blue` for the latter!

Comment: @Idle_Mind How should go about it to see the painting after the loop? I dont need to see one changes at a time, just need to see all changes done at the end.

Comment: @TaW I am dumping all onto Bitmap first, then let picturebox image equal Bitmap. Can explain what does "leaking your Font and even the Brush" means? sorry I'm still new to C# winform

Comment: C# will take care of freeing all memory except for thoese things that implement IDisposable. This includes many GDI resorces like Bitmap, Fonts Brushes etc.. - -So you need to either call Dispose on them or use them in a `using` clause. If you don't, sooner or later the apllication will crash for lack of either memory or gdi handles..

Comment: I've edited my question.anyone can tell me why aren't the bottom code not drawing anything?

Comment: @user10748500 - You're trying to redraw inside a loop. That doesn't work.You need to let winforms to paint the invalidated area after your method exits to see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

If we're in the Paint() event, then I'd expect to see something more like this:

```
if (Tagged_Remarks_listBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    Font drawFont = new Font("Calibri (Body)", 15);
    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
    for (int x = 1; x <= NumberingPosition.Count - 1; x++)
    {       
        //MessageBox.Show(Numbering[u] + NumberingPosition[u]);
        gr.DrawString(Numbering[x], drawFont, drawBrush, NumberingPosition[x]);
    }
    drawFont.Dispose();
    drawBrush.Dispose();
}
```

Note that calling Invalidate() in the Paint() would cause it to repaint itself **REPEATEDLY** and **FOREVER**...which might be part of the problem.

Comment: I put an "if" statement in my "for" loop to filter out the first "gr.Drawstring" because I do not want it to be drawn. I tried adding "Dispose" but doesnt show any difference when running the app. Why does adding "MessageBox.Show" somehow make the gr.Drawstring execute(but its still abit buggy and messagebox keep pop-ing up non-stop) .

Comment: I skipped the first one by changing `x=0` to `x=1`.

Comment: **Where** is this code executing from?  What event?...perhaps that might be a problem as well.

Comment: Oh yeah true, noted! I used the code u provided and I get exactly same results as before . thanks anyway man!

Comment: Its executing from "Paint" event

Comment: The Paint() event...do you need to save the modified bitmap?  If not, just draw onto the supplied `e.Graphics` (in the Paint() event) instead.

Comment: Yes i need to save the modified Bitmap.

Comment: You can still save the "modified" bitmap when using the supplied `e.Graphics`.  Look up the [PictureBox.DrawToBitmap()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_DrawToBitmap_System_Drawing_Bitmap_System_Drawing_Rectangle_) method.

Comment: You'd create a new Bitmap the same size as your PictureBox and then pass that to DrawToBitmap().

Comment: Is your suggestion the same as what I'm doing now? The way im doing it is to create a bitmap that look exactly like the drawing which is want to draw on. After i draw on the bitmap, i will declare picturebox.image=bm. Actually i have one part in my Paint() event that sucessfully able to "paint" something. Just that it is initiated by cursor click position, while this part which i'm asking is drawn based on the saved drawing(Using saved "Point"s) .

Comment: Not exactly the same, no.  Drawing on to `e.Graphics` draws "on top" of the image there.  It's not permanent unless you use the mentioned `DrawToBitmap()` approach.  The background image would stay the same and doesn't need to be changed/reset.  You simply change what is happening in the `Paint()` event to change what is on top of the PictureBox.

Comment: However, I need to save the edited image into png in the future, will that be possible?

Comment: Sure, that's still possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work(Maybe not the best, most effective, efficient way), by using Bitmap to take in all the drawings. This bitmap will then be saved as a Png file. Once all drawings are done, I declare the picturebox.image as the bitmap's Png file.

```
private void Side_pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (Tagged_Remarks_listBox.SelectedIndex == 0 && selectedindexreset == true)
    {
        //Side_pictureBox.ImageLocation = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"pictures for app\Bus_Nearside.png";
        Side_pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\pictures for app\Bus_Nearside.png");
        Bitmap bmforedit = new Bitmap(Side_pictureBox.Image);

        //MessageBox.Show("inside");

        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmforedit))
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= NumberingPosition.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
                if (Numbering[x] != "1") // change accordingly
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(Numbering[x]);
                    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    Font drawFont = new Font("Calibri (Body)", 15);
                    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
                    //MessageBox.Show(Numbering[x] + NumberingPosition[x]);

                    gr.DrawString(Numbering[x], drawFont, drawBrush, NumberingPosition[x]);

                    drawFont.Dispose();
                    drawBrush.Dispose();
                }
            }
            // bmforedit.Save(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\PDI_APP_EDIT_FOR_TO\PDIPROTOTYPE2\bin\Debug\pictures for app\TestImage.png");
            Side_pictureBox.Image.Dispose();
            //bmforedit.Save(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\PDI_APP_EDIT_FOR_TO\PDIPROTOTYPE2\bin\Debug\pictures for app\TestImage1.png");
            Side_pictureBox.Image = bmforedit;
        }

        for (int u = 0; u <= PrevStore.Count - 1; u++)
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmforedit))
            {
                if (u < StartDrawCount[0] || u > StopDrawCount[0])
                {
                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.DarkRed, 2), PrevStore[u], NowStore[u]);
                    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                }
            }
        }

        bmforedit.Save(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\PDI_APP_EDIT_FOR_TO\PDIPROTOTYPE2\bin\Debug\pictures for app\TestImage2.png");
        selectedindexreset = false;
        Side_pictureBox.ImageLocation = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"pictures for app\TestImage2.png";
        Side_pictureBox.Refresh();
    }
}
```